# Mdam Raid Is fine but Primary GPT Table is corrupt

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm, gpt

Im running mdadm raid one with two drives of different sizes. I have a partition on the bigger drive that is the same size as the smaller drive and then mdadm uses the partition and the whole smaller drive to make the raid. when I do fdisk -l I get [THIS](https://pastebin.com/7qmkfsnz) and it says the smaller drives primary gpt table is corrupt. Looking at the raid, it seems fine as seem [HERE](https://pastebin.com/zrAwXueW)

Comment: Are you syncing sda with sdb2. And then that is why gdisk is giving error on sda as it finds older partitions?

Comment: @oldfred that is exactly what I'm doing. To clarify the other comment, I am using RAID 1 so the data is on both drives.

Comment: I think that is then the confusion, I do not know RAID, but think it should be sda2 and sdb2? Or is it all of sda & all of sdb?

Comment: I missed the RAID 1 part.  Just out of curiosity, why did you go with a RAID 1 on two different sized drives?  You lost 500GB of usable space.  It appears that you are missing the boot partition on your `/dev/sdb` drive which can also cause problems in the future if your `/dev/sda` drive dies that you will not have a boot sector available for the system to boot from for recovery purposes.  Also, to correct corrupted GPT partitions where the backup is good you use `gdisk` to correct those.  If not installed, `sudo apt install gdisk`